# PHP to delete SQL row with multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to delete multiple rows with chekboxes. Below is my code

```
      <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="****"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="****"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="****"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE dealer='Panzer Protection'");
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#666666"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]"    
value="<? echo $rows['member_id']; ?>"></td>
        <td bgcolor="#666666"><? echo $rows['member_id']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#666666"><center>
          <? echo $rows['member_msisdn']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#666666"><center>
          <? echo $rows['member_name']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#666666"><div align="center"><? echo $rows['dealer']; ?></div>   

 </td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="control_clientinfo.php?member_id=   
<? echo $rows['member_id']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit"     
id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

</form> //Forgot form close in past
<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 
if($_POST['delete']){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$i = 0;
while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST['checkbox'])) {
$sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$val'";
mysql_query($sql);
$i += mysql_affected_rows();
}
}
// if successful redirect to 
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=control_clientlistdel.php\">";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

It shows me the list i call and i can tick the boxes. If i hit delete button it just refreshes the screen and the one i ticked is still there

Comment: Your DELETE query is prone to SQL injection. Properly escape user contents or, better, learn about parametrized queries. Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). And use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting database fields to your HTML markup to prevent XSS. And the `bgcolor` and `align` attributes are deprecated. And the `center` element, too.

Comment: Where does your form close?

Comment: Also, to capture the button being clicked you should use something like $_POST["delete"]. Do NOT use just $delete. This used to be a method with the old PHP 4 and earlier but this is no longer accepted. Furthermore, you should check for the delete BEFORE you print the results. Otherwise it will print the records and then delete. Makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.
It's bad idea to use `mysql` as it is really old and it's deprecated.

Second, where do you assign your variables (`$delete`, `$count`)

you have to check if the `delete` key of your `POST` is set:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) { // Then the form has been submitted
```

after this, assign your `$count` variable

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$count = count($checkbox);
```

And everything must work fine.

Final result

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checkbox);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $id = (int) $checkbox[$i]; // Parse your value to integer

        if ($id > 0) { // and check if it's bigger then 0
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE member_id = $id");
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) drivers for interacting with the database.

Comment: @ Mirmko Akkov your method worked I just had a typo in $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_id='$val'"; hust had id instead of member_id

Comment: Instead of performing a query delete one record, it's much faster to run 1 query that deletes all desired records. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599303/php-to-delete-sql-row-with-multiple-checkboxes/20175242#20175242).

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its a typo or not.. but you you have a missing `from` end tags and `<table>` in the posted code..

```
....
<td colspan="6" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
</form> //here
```

and you need to check the posted `$delete` value in if condition..the correct way is to use `$_POST` since you are using method as pos.. here `method="post"`.

**updated**

```
 if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['delete']){ //here
     $count=count($_POST['checkbox']);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      $sql  = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='".$_POST['checkbox'][$i]."'";
      mysql_query($sql);

     }
}
```

you can use [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect in php

```
 header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/ontrol_clientlistdel.php' ) ;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: 
if($_POST['delete']){

and yes i forgot the </form> when pasting

Comment: @TrevorAckermann: Use `if (isset($_POST['delete']))` to test if `delete` exists in the POST array.

Comment: Now you only check if `$_POST` exists, not whether or not the `delete` index is present.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){  Error I am gettin now